# Xamarin Visual Studio Install Package Unhandled Exception

Tags: c#, android, mono, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I figured I'd try out Xamarin's Mono Android, but right from the start, it doesn't work on my device.

This only happens if I try to load the app from within VS to my I9100, but works fine if loaded to an emulator.

My device has CM10 with debugging enabled. The solution itself is out-of-the-box with only the AndroidManifest added and customized to the very basics.

Tried checking and unchecking Shared Runtime and Use Fast Deployment. Linking is set to Sdk and User Assemblies.

The details of the Exception are:
InstallFailedException: [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
at
Mono.AndroidTools.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String PackageName)
at
Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice<>c_DisplayClass27.b_26(Task'1 t)
at
System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask'1.InnerInvoke()
at
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue was due to the custom kernel I am using. I'm using Dorimanx's 7.1 JB Mali (based on Siyah) which needed to have its ADB mode set to development under Misc options in ExTweaks. Hope this helps others who found themselves stuck with this issue.